# Split array into halves, quarters etc

Tags: java, list, split

I am looking for a way to split array in half (with middle number not included in any half) until the last created array containts only one number. The middle number is either exactly in the middle (for example, for **[1,2,3,4,5]** it is **3**) or the first number of the 2nd half of array (for **[1,2,3,4,5,6]** it would be **4**)

Let's say i have an array:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I shoud get:

```
[1,2,3,4,5] [7,8,9,10]

[1,2] [4,5] [7,8] [10]

[2]    [5]   [8]
```

I tried recursion, however it always divides only one half of an array

```
public int[][] divide(int[] values, int[][] split_values, int index) {
  int root_index = 0;
  if(values.length > 1) {
    if(values.length % 2 != 0) {
        root_index = (values.length - 1) / 2;
    }
    else {
        root_index = (int) ((values.length) / 2);
    }
    int[] left_value = new int[root_index-1];
    int[] right_value = new int[values.length - left_value.length - 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if(i < left_value.length) {
            left_value[i] = values[i];
        }
        else {
            right_value[i] = values[i];
        }
    }

    split_values[index] = left_value;
    index++;
    split_values[index] = right_value;
    index++;
  }
  for(int[] value : split_values) {
        divide(value, split_values, index);
  }
  return split_values;
}
```

EDIT: so i changed it a bit, the function now accepts parameters

```
 int[] values, int[][] split_values, String used, int index
 ...
 if(values.length > 1) {
 ...
 used += "!" + Arrays.toString(values) + "!";
 }

     for(int[] value : split_values) {
    if(!used.contains("!" + Arrays.toString(value) + "!")) {
            divide(value, split_values, used, index);
    }        
}
```

Now the problem is that it's a never-ending cycle.

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a free code writing service.

Comment: edited my comment

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I think I'm getting closer. My function now looks like this: **public int[][] divide(int[] values, int[][] split_values, String used, int index) {** where I put all divided arrays into string "used". Now the problem is that the program is a never-ending cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

preserves all elements:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
        splitTo(array);
    }

    static void splitTo(Integer[] source) {
        int length = source.length;
        if (length == 1) return;
        boolean odd = length % 2 != 0;
        int half1 = length / 2;
        int half2 = odd ? half1 + 1 : half1;
        Integer[] one = new Integer[half1];
        Integer[] two = new Integer[half2];
        int index = 0;
        for (Integer element : one) {
            one[index] = source[index];
            two[index] = source[half1 + index];
            index++;
        }
        if (odd) two[index] = source[half1 + index];
        Integer[][] integers = {one, two};
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(integers));
        splitTo(one);
        splitTo(two);
    }
```

rejecting middle one:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
        splitTo(array);
    }

    static void splitTo(Integer[] source) {
        int length = source.length;
        if (length == 1) return;
        boolean odd = length % 2 != 0;
        int half = length / 2;
        Integer[] one = new Integer[half];
        Integer[] two = new Integer[half];
        int index = 0;
        for (Integer element : one) {
            one[index] = source[index];
            two[index] = odd ? source[half + index + 1] : source[half + index];
            index++;
        }
        Integer[][] integers = {one, two};
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(integers));
        splitTo(one);
        splitTo(two);
    }
```

good practice will be if you study MergeSort algorithm
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort